# Border-radius not rendering in Chrome on retina display

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've encountered strange behaviour while building a circular progress indicator. After trying to isolate the bug I'm out of clues why the border-radius isn't rendered in Chrome on retina displays.

I've got a div which renders a circle and some inner content which is positioned absolute:

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Of course this renders just fine.
However, by adding a few surrounding div's it starts to show a rectangle instead of a circle.

```
<div style="height: 300px"> <!-- to render scrollbar -->
  <div style="position: fixed"></div>
  <div style="position: relative"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The isolated issue: https://codepen.io/sanderdejong/pen/qmrXjq

Things which turn the rectangle into a circle again:

- Lower the height of the top div so it won't render a scrollbar
- Scroll the page so that the rectangle is partially out of bounds
- Drag the browser window to a non-retina monitor
- Remove the position relative or fixed from one of the sibling div's

I'm not sure how I can isolate the issue even further and if it is explainable why this happens. I also tried Firefox and Safari but both work correctly.

Comment: I've found a similar issue with a different outcome. Chrome border-radius on a retina display is showing a weird ghost pixel around the edge of the circle. This does not happen in FireFox or Safari. No answer, but something to note for anyone looking for symptoms they may be encountering.